# products and categories are not indexed as per custom template in Sitecore Commerce 10

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have created new template "My Commerce Category" by inheriting from "/sitecore/templates/Project/Sitecore/Commerce Category" and have added new section "addition" with field "notes". I did apply the custom category template on "Habitat_master" and refreshed the commerce cache so I can see the template is applied on the category.

[image]

But when I am building my master index, I still see the template name is "Commerce Catalog". Any idea why it is not picking up custom template?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to patch Sitecore config `\App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.TemplateGenerator.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <commerceEngineTemplateGenerator type="Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.Configuration.TemplateGeneratorConfiguration, Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect">
      <baseTemplates hint="raw:AddBaseTemplates">
        <!-- Catalog -->
        <template id="{93AF861A-B6F4-45BE-887D-D93D4B95B39D}">
          <!--<baseTemplate></baseTemplate>-->
        </template>

        <!-- Category -->
        <template id="{4C4FD207-A9F7-443D-B32A-50AA33523661}">
          <!--<baseTemplate></baseTemplate>-->
        </template>

        <!-- Sellable Item -->
        <template id="{225F8638-2611-4841-9B89-19A5440A1DA1}">
          <!--<baseTemplate></baseTemplate>-->
        </template>
      </baseTemplates>
      <!-- Defines the catalog item to use for template generation -->
      <catalogId></catalogId>
      <!-- Defines the category item to use for template generation -->
      <categoryId></categoryId>
      <!-- Defines the sellable item to use for template generation -->
      <sellableItemId></sellableItemId>
      <!-- Defines the bundle to use for template generation -->
      <bundleId></bundleId>
    </commerceEngineTemplateGenerator>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I would suggest to create your custom template as a base template and add it to the `baseTemplates` of Category via patch.